# Using npm as a library

Tags: node.js, npm

I have been trying to understand how to make `npm` work as a library for quite a long time now.
Here is what I have been doing, but it feels quite evident to me that this isn't the proper way to do such a thing. Say that I want to install the library `sqlite3`.

Here is what I have been doing:

```
mkdir npmtest
cd npmtest
npm init
npm install --save npm
node
```

And inside node, I just do

```
var npm = require('npm');
npm.load(function()
{
   npm.install('sqlite3')
});
```

It does... things. Like it shows a progress bar in the terminal, then it just crashes with a huge amount of errors. I have pasted them [here](http://pastebin.com/J7stWf5r).

I am evidently doing something wrong. How can I get this working? I need to be using `npm` as a library, I cannot make use of the command line tool, since I will be distributing my app with Atom Electron, and I cannot assume that npm will be installed where I deploy my app.